# How to avoid async/Promise antipattern with `childProcess.spawn`?

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await, es6-promise

I'm writing node.js (v10+) code in typescript (3.8.3+). I want to wrap `childProcess.spawn()` for my use case.

I have something like this so far, which is working but I know that creating explicit Promises in an async function is usually wrong.

```
// Returns a promise that resolves when the subprocess completes.
export async function runSubprocess(cmd: string, args: string[],
                                    onStdout?: (msg: string) => void)
                                    onStart?: (subproc) => Promise<void>) {
  // note: don't do anything async between creating the subproc and setting up
  // its event handlers, to avoid race conditions.
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let stdout: string = ''
    let stderr: string = ''

    const subproc = childProcess.spawn(cmd, args)
    subproc.stdout.on('data', msg => {
      // accumulate all stdout into messages
      stdout += msg
      if (onStdout) { onStdout(msg) }
    })
    subproc.stderr.on('data', msg => { stderr += msg })
    subproc.on('error', e => {
      throw new SubprocessError(`Error starting ${cmd} ${args}`, e)
    })
    subproc.on('close', async (code, signal) => {
      if (code == 0) {
        resolve(0)
      } else {
        throw new SubprocessError(`Subproc ${cmd} ${args} returned error ${code} (signal: ${signal}\n STDOUT:\n${stdout}\n STDERR:\n${stderr}\n`)
      }
    })

    if (onStart)
      await onStart(subproc)
  })
```

The goals are:

- Make it awaitable
- Allow for an async `onStart()` callback
- Make it resolve when the subprocess is done (on 'close')

So this looks suspiciously to me like the antipattern of creating a new Promise in an async function. But I don't see how to get rid of the explicit `Promise` while keeping all my goals. I need it to resolve *something* when the subprocess is done, and I need to be able to await onStart before returning, so I can't remove the top-level "async".

Note that `onStart` is supposed to run as soon as the subproc is created and the handlers are in place -- not wait for the proc to complete, hence the await there.

Comment: Actually the code as written here _doesn't_ work -- I can't `await onStart()` because the Promise callback isn't async. So I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: There is the [`child-process-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/child-process-promise) package which does the heavy lifting for you, maybe you could use that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `async` on `runSubprocess`, you can put it on the anonymous function in the Promise constructor:

```
// Returns a promise that resolves when the subprocess completes.
export function runSubprocess(cmd: string, args: string[],
                                    onStdout?: (msg: string) => void)
                                    onStart?: (subproc) => Promise<void>) {
  // note: don't do anything async between creating the subproc and setting up
  // its event handlers, to avoid race conditions.
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
...
```

Additionally, you might want to reject when your get an error:

```
...
    subproc.on('error', e => {
      reject(new SubprocessError(`Error starting ${cmd} ${args}`, e))
    })
...
```

Or as @CherryDT suggests, use a library for it.

Comment: Did you mean `new SubprocessError`?